# Can't access my local site through IE using https and self-signed certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, https, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have a web application and self-signed certificate. When I use Chrome/Firefox, 'https://localhost:443/mysite/' works fine. But in IE9 I can't access my site.

There is a button "Continue to this website (not recommended)" which does not work at all! 
What should I do, to test my site on https and IE9 simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you click on "Continue to this website (not recommended)"? Be specific.

Comment: Page refreshed and nothing changed.

Comment: Do you still see the warning page?

Comment: I've tried many many times click this f**** button

Comment: IE 10 doesn't even have this button! What is wrong with miycrausoft..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed key algorithm from RSA to DSA and all start works fine. Thanks to all.

Comment: 1024 Bit RSA works as well. It's only the default 512 Bit that makes the problems in IE.

Comment: @chessweb - How do you change this?

Answer (score 2):

In IE go to Tools > Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites > Sites and click Add to add the sites URL as trusted.

Go back to the website - you will likely still get the self signed warning. Click continue to website. Then when on the page Right Click and select Properties then Certificates Add the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Pretty sure that is it (going from memory).

Answer (score 2):

I've been reading on the web that this is related to a Windows Update that restricts access to RSA certificates using less than 1024 bit keys.  The 'preferred' solution is to use stronger keys.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661254

Answer (score 0):

After trying numerous suggestions to resolve this issue, manually creating the shortcut did the trick. I do not understand the reason, but it worked, so I am happy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a good idea to use `//127.0.0.1` instead of `//localhost` - worked for me in IE and Safari with a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

So, it didn't work for me.

My problem was, I was trying to access a web-interface on a local server (`https://192.168.1.1:8773/userinterface.jsp`), and the only option in IE10 was to close the webpage. (worked fine in chrome)

Tried several solutions and found this:

The new .website shortcuts created by IE (in my case by dragging the URL icon to the desktop) are complete garbage.

Solution:

Delete all the website shortcuts created with Internet Explorer and create your own ones:

Right-click on your Desktop and select “New- Shortcut”
Enter the target URL e.g. http://www.google.de
Enter the name for the link
Click OK to finish the wizard.

Works like a charm. Just make sure you don't have a .website extension when you look at the file properties of your shortcut.

Comment: Actually this is the right answer to the question: Using an auto-generated shortcut, IE10 does not offer the option _Continue to this Website_. How come? Even if the self signed certificate is valid.